# IE position anchor element over an image

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, xhtml

I'm having an issue with IE9(and 8) with positioning empty(kinda) anchor elements over an image. The anchors contains text, but it's kicked off the page using CSS's text-indent property.

I'm working on a site that has a series of promo panels, they're all contained in an UL. Inside each LI there's a promo image, and 1 or more anchor elements positioned over different areas of it. The IMG and the A elements are absolutely positioned in the LI element. So, the basic structure looks like UL > LI > IMG A A A.

This setup works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but IE doesn't like it. I've tried using z-index on this setup with no luck.

Can anyone explain the issue that IE is having, and give a better solution for my CSS? *I've made a quick/simplified example of my problem using a div, img, and a single anchor.* This can be copy/pasted onto your machine to see it in action.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta name="Description" content="" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="" />
        <style type="text/css">
            #div {
                z-index:1;
                display: block;
                background:red;
                position:relative;
            }
            #image {
                z-index:2;
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                display:block;
            }
            #anchor {
                z-index:3;
                display:block;
                overflow:hidden;
                position: absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                text-indent:-9999px;
                width:640px;
                height:480px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div">
            <img id="image" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7130/7438112718_2e8340081b_z.jpg" />
            <a href="#" id="anchor">clicky</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't have much control over the UL > LI > IMG A layout. This is setup that as we get new promos we can easily update the image, and just add or remove anchors easily depending on how many 'calls to action' the image has. The positioning of the A elements are injected inline.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to show anchor tag on the image?

Comment: Yeah, the anchor tag should be clickable over the image, and take up the area specificed in the CSS. Currently, it's there, and is the size of the dimensions given in CSS, but not clickable.

Comment: Means you want to show the text and even the image should be clickable? kinda image should act as `anchor` tag?

Comment: The text should not show, it's moved off the page with CSS. There will be one image with multiple anchors on top of it that should be clickable. If it were just one image & anchor, I'd put the img tag inside the anchor..but again there will be multiple clickable areas for one image.

Comment: did you referred both fiddles of mine?

Comment: I'll check now.. I didn't notice you'd posted an answer until just now. Thanks.

Comment: I deleted as it was not useful for you

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Using your example, here's my solution:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #div {
        position:relative;
    }
    #anchor {
        display:block;
        width:640px;
        height:480px;
        overflow:hidden;
        text-indent:-9999px;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        background:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7130/7438112718_2e8340081b_z.jpg) no-repeat 640px 480px;
    }
</style>

<div id="div">
    <img id="image" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7130/7438112718_2e8340081b_z.jpg" />
    <a href="#" id="anchor">clicky</a>
</div>
```

Since the anchor tag has a set width and height with overflow hidden, set the anchor tag's background image to the image that it's absolutely positioned over (or any image you've already included), BUT set the background-position to positive pixel values larger than the anchor's width and height and background-repeat to no-repeat. By doing this, the anchor tags work in IE, AND the browser doesn't download extra resources so you save bandwidth. Note: the img tag doesn't need any special styling, and the containing div only needs position relative.

If you don't want to worry about setting the background-position, don't have control over the size of any dynamically generated images, and/or aren't concerned about saving bandwidth, you could also create and use a small (1x1) clear/transparent image (set background-repeat if necessary).

Alternately, augmenting Billy Moat's fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/7NpLq/29/

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use a plain old HTML image map to achieve what you're wanting here:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Otherwise here's a fiddle doing what I think you were trying to do originally:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/7NpLq/

Comment: Your fiddle is what I'm trying to acomplish, and it works in IE until you remove the background color. Any ideas? The way this page is setup I don't have the option of switching it to use an image map. Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: @snowBlind - So exactly what is it you want to achieve that's different from my fiddle?

Comment: Exactly what your fiddle does, but have it still work once you remove the background color from the anchors.

Answer (score 0):

This issue affects IE10 as well, but not IE11. An alternative to the background image approach is to apply `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);` to the anchor. Note that this won't work in IE8, which doesn't support `rgba` colors.